# Can I switch between windows of the same app using plank?

Tags: plank, window-management

I have to work on multiple code branches that requires me to launch multiple instances of IntelliJ IDE. But when navigating between these instances I find it very difficult to switch to specific instance. I currently do via global windows spread which is very difficult when you have many applications opened. For example in a dock like Cairo when a mouse over a application icon give a concise spread of similar applications (also as in Mac) to switch.

This applies for any application not just IntelliJ, for example when multiple instance of "File manager" is opened and try to navigate to the specific instance.

Can that be done in plank? If so please let me know how to do that?

Comment: I am confused as to why this is being flagged as off-topic, could someone elaborate?

Comment: Also, you might be looking for the context entries. Just right-click an item in plank and you can see a list of open windows for that application.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me. However I feel mouse over would be more intuitive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either scroll over the icon in plank, or right-click it for a context menu which includes open windows of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really apreciate it. But, what if I want to do this switch through keyboard? There is any shortcut? If not, how can I create a custom shortcut, I mean, which command I need to set on custom shortcuts dialog?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Tab should do it, it open all open windows and you can choose one.

Comment: In gernal that's ok but it has nothing to do with the plank-dock where we want to switch between multiple windows. Look at the other marked solution.