# How does one cycle through windows of the same application?

Tags: applications, keyboard-shortcuts, window-management

I have two questions.

1. What is the default keystroke for cycling through windows in an application, e.g., evince?
2. How can I change this default?

Currently, Alt-tab cycles through all windows, but I only want to cycle through windows of the same application.

Comment: is  Ctrl + PgUp/PgDn really working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: This is not the correct answer for the above question. When i wrote this i was thinking about tabs of an application and not windows. So, this answer works for cycling through tabs of an app.**

`Ctrl` + `PgUp/PgDn` is the default keyboard shortcut to cycle through windows/tabs in an application.

In some applications if `Ctrl` + `PgUp/PgDn` doesn't work, try `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `PgUp/PgDn`

Here is a list of keyboard shortcuts in elementary: [elementary os keyboard shortcuts](http://lmelinux.net/2014/07/26/elementary-os-keyboard-shortcuts/)

You can also refer to the answer to this question [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/what-are-the-different-methods-to-switch-between-windows-and-workspaces), which is similar to yours.

For a detailed reading: [learning elementary basics](https://elementary.io/docs/learning-the-basics#app-windows)

Comment: What if we are stuck on a keyboard without PgUp/PgDn (such as a Macbook keyboard)?

Comment: On a MacBook or similar keyboard, you can hit Fn-Up/Fn-Down for PgUp/PgDn.

Comment: @cipricus The above answer is not correct for this question. I have given the shortcut for cycling through tabs of app not windows and yes i did check this on firefox and files(tabs).

Comment: The initial phrasing of the question was indeed obscure, namely "windows in the same application", which may have suggested tabs. - That being said, the OP mentions Evince ('Document viewer'), which doesn't use tabs. - And, as far as tabs are concerned, CTRTL-TAB is also an option [in many cases](http://askubuntu.com/a/883958/47206).

Comment: Thanks for the macbook tip @RyanDeBeasi. This shortcut doesn't work for terminal, do you know what the shortcut there is?

Comment: Try control-shift-right and control-shift-left. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/983/792

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to cycle ONLY between windows of the same application when other windows are open *in the same workspace*?

#### I think the answer is NO.

I cannot confirm the other answer that was also marked as definitive.

Because it doesn't work, other questions ([here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10394/170) and [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10705/170)) asking for an answer are marked or can be marked as duplicate of the present question.

At the same time the present question can be marked as duplicate of this one: [What are the different methods to switch between windows and workspaces?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1441/170), which specifically mentions at its first point: `windows of the same application on the same workspace`.

But that point is not mentioned by [Daniel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/45/daniel-for%C3%A9) Foré's authoritative [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1479/170), which makes me think that in fact the answer to the question ***"how it is possible to cycle exclusevely between windows of the same application"*** is that "it's not possible".

---

The absence of this option is probably due to the presence of others - as indicated in  [Daniel Foré's answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/45/daniel-for%C3%A9) - which achieve the same goal.

The way the Pantheon desktop uses workspaces is very intelligent. There is no new empty workspace, and any fullscreen window (<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>) gets its own workspace.

To achieve the goal: **open the multi-window application (and only that) in its own workspace and then switch windows there with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.** If you need more than one multi-window application, use separate workspaces for each app, and switch between apps by switching workspaces (<kbd>Super-</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
To create new workspaces for windows as said before, just make fullscreen window (<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>) or use the shortkey that shows workspaces (<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>,<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>) - those can be customized) and drop the windows of your application onto the **+** button to add new workspace.

[image]

Comment: I think the functionality is implemented, but there is no keyboard shortcut for it. Placing the mouse pointer over the icon in plank and rotating the mouse wheel, you can change between the instances of the application. So, all you need to know is how to create a custom shortcut (what action to link it to).

Comment: @RandomUser - yet, looking in all the answers posted under different questions (see links) there is no such action identified. The other answer here mentions Ctrl + PgUp/PgDn, but it doesn't work for me and  I haven't found that in the shortcuts list.

Comment: @ cipricus - I have extracted information from this same forum, specifically this question: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3250/7029

Comment: @RandomUser - couldn't that be a Plank action (that **cannot** be triggered by a shortcut) and not one of the window manager (that **can** be triggered by shortcut)? - I was just amazed that even though this was asked four times, including one that got an answer from Daniel Foré, the specific command/shortcut that would only switch between the windows  of a selected app was never to be found (except that odd answer mentioning  Ctrl + PgUp/PgDn).

Comment: @ cipricus - You're right. That action is Plank related only. So all of us, without knowledge about vala coding, we can only wait until some vala developer can implement this functionality into window manager.

Comment: @RandomUser - after looking a bit more into it my impression is that workspaces serve exactly this purpose of separating windows in groups. If all windows of the same app have one exclusive workspace, then Alt+Tab serves the purpose and no supplementary shortcut is really needed. My impression now is that the need for that shortcut we talk about comes only from a one-workspace mentality. :)

Comment: @ cipricus - You're right. Maybe the problem is myself, because I work with two screens and I only use one workspace. Maybe is time to change to multi-workspace environment. Thank you for your comments.