# Is there a keyboard shortcut for cycling through windows of the same application?

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts

In Mac OSX this is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>
Is there an equivalent for Elementary? I didn't see it as an option in the key

Answer (score 1):

If you have a US Keyboard <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles through *all* the windows.

And yes, to cycle within a tabbed application:

- Firefox:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (forwards) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (backwards)
- Files: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (forwards) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (backwards)

PS: I think shortcuts can also depend upon the application used.

Comment: Feel free to update this answer and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, [there isn't](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/how-does-one-cycle-through-windows-of-the-same-application) a keyboard shortcut for that, presumably because of how workspaces are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Workspaces provide an alternative for some workflows and though I make heavy use of them for different purposes I have not found them to be an efficient alternative to [Alt + ` ] for cycling through windows of the same application in my daily workflow.

I use [a python script](https://gist.github.com/tysonholub/c737d562614aa0d83add66dbec378723) invoked by a custom keyboard shortcut as outlined in the code comments to accomplish this. This has worked well on Juno and Hera.